# SQL Server - stored procedure (update table) - Insert new rows, update existing ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I need to update several rows from a table in a single operation.

What I'd normally do, is to delete (soft delete) all previous records with the same foreign key and insert everything again. But this is not optimal at all and now that my job actually involves having to create stored procedures I wanted to know it there was a 'standard' way to perform this kind of operations.

Take these images as an example:

1. This is the original data associated with the foreign key (`ParentId`) 1:

   [image]
2. Then using the corresponding interface I make the following changes:

   [image]

   a) In the second row, the column `Name` (in yellow) was changed
   b) The third row (in red) was removed
   c) The fourth and fifth rows (in green) are new. Because these rows reside only on the client side I don't have a primary key (Id) for them
3. This is what I would like to end up with:

   [image]

So far I've created a new type :

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE name='T_DetailDomain') BEGIN
    DROP TYPE dbo.T_DetailDomain;
END;
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.T_DetailDomain AS TABLE
(
    Id             INT NOT NULL,
    Name           VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    Abbrev         VARCHAR (300) NOT NULL,
    ParentId       INT NOT NULL 
);
GO
```

And this is the signature of the procedure:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.up_DetailDomain_Update 
    @pParentId  INT,
    @pTableDetail dbo.T_DetailDomain READONLY
AS
```

As you can see I pass all the rows as a table-valued parameter (`@pTableDetail`).

Is there any 'standard' way I can achieve what I described above?

Or do I have to perform three operations:

1. Insert all the rows without an Id
2. update all the rows with an existing Id
3. remove all the rows with an Id not present in the table-valued parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking to MERGE data.  you can use merge (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) there are instances not to do so performance wise and things but then you just first an update statement with inner join then an insert statement and then a delete statement constrained to non joined records....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806768/sql-merge-statement-to-update-data

Comment: @Matt But is it common to use this Merge statement to perform an update? Would you use it yourself? I'm a front-end developer taking its first steps into the SQL world, so please bear with me.

Comment: yeah it is pretty common but as an ETL developer for larger datasets I still prefer the 3 statements.  there are a few issues with MERGE https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/ but most of the issues with it are edge cases if you have a pretty simple data base structure meaning not lots of triggers etc.  I will say performance is better with the 3 separate statements but if you are not working with large datasets it likely won't matter