# Check if rows exists in SQL Server using R and then Insert or Update rows

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I have a table with the below structure.

```
ID Entity UserName UserRole UserStatus UpdatedDate
```

Clustered key is defined on columns `Entity, UserName, UserRole`.

`UserStatus` for an `Entity-UserName-UserRole` could be either `Active` or `Inactive`.

I could implement the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements for a `dataframe` **df** as follows:

Insert:

```
values <- paste("('",df$Entity,"','", df$UserName,"','",
                    ,df$UserRole,"','" ,df$UserStatus,"','" ,
                    df$UpdatedDate"')", sep="", collapse=",")
   
sqlStr_Insert<- sqlQuery(con, sprintf(paste("Insert into TBL
                                     (Entity, UserName,UserRole,UserStatus,UpdatedDate) values ",values)))
```

Update:

```
sql_string <- "UPDATE TBL SET UserStatus = '%s', UpdatedDate = '%s' WHERE Entity='%s' AND UserName ='%s' AND UserRole = '%s';"
  
  sqlStr_update <-sqlQuery(con, paste(sprintf(sql_string, UserStatus, UpdatedDate,df$Entity,df$UserName,df$UserRole), collapse=""))
```

The code works fine but I would like it to check if for every row in the df for a combination of Entity-UserName-UserRole already exists in the TBL. If found, run the UPDATE statement else run the INSERT statement.

For example - SQL Server table data:

```
ID Entity UserName UserRole UserStatus UpdatedDate
---------------------------------------------------
1  A      Ford    Analyst  Active     1/1/2020
2  B      Acura   Analyst  Active     1/5/2020
3  A      Tesla   Engineer Inactive   1/6/2020
4  A      Kia     Analyst  Active     1/1/2020
```

df to be inserted or updated:

```
 Entity UserName UserRole UserStatus UpdatedDate
---------------------------------------------------
 A      Accord   Analyst  Active     1/10/2020
 B      Acura    Analyst  Active     1/10/2020
 C      BMW      Engineer Active     1/10/2020
```

What should happen:

Only rows 1st and 3rd should get '`INSERTED`' to the database TBL. `UPDATE` should only happen if the '`UserStatus`' changes for an `existing Entity-UserName-UserRole` Combination.

I guess I could run a 'FOR' loop for every row of the dataframe df but I think that would be slow and not an optimum solution.

Comment: You need `MERGE`. Or two separate statements: an `INSERT...WHERE NOT EXISTS` and a joined `UPDATE`. You may want to look at passing through a Table-Valued Parameter and do it all in one batch. And your current code is **wide open to SQL injection and syntax errors, use parameterized queries instead**

Comment: okay good point. I do perform numerous data checks before Insert/Update, so the df gets populated with 'valid' data. The above code passes the entire df in one go to the SQL server. How would I write the MERGE statement in this scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL MERGE statement to update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806768/sql-merge-statement-to-update-data)

Comment: partly as it does not mention how to perform SQL merge statement in R using the data frame. I will try it anyways.

Comment: CodeMaster, I suspect that the sql "merge" command is what you need. In many circles, this operation is referred to as an "UPSERT", where you update if it exists (based on one or more keys) and insert if not. I know of no R function that does it natively (though the [`dbx`](https://github.com/ankane/dbx) package supports other DBMSes, not sqlserver, perhaps they'll add it at some point). Waldi's two-step approach is what I've been using for a few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a temporary table (use `#` prefix in `SQL Server`) and send a `MERGE` query as [suggested by @CharlieFace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806768/sql-merge-statement-to-update-data):

```
data.new <- read.table(text='
Entity UserName UserRole UserStatus UpdatedDate
A      Accord   Analyst  Active     1/10/2020
B      Acura    Analyst  Active     1/10/2020
C      BMW      Engineer Active     1/10/2020', header = T)



library(DBI)
conn <- dbConnect(...)

# Create temporary table
dbWriteTable(conn,'#NEWDATA',data.new)

dbExecute(conn,"
MERGE INTO TBL WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING #NEWDATA AS source
    ON target.Entity = source.Entity
    AND target.UserName = source.UserName
    AND target.UserRole = source.UserRole
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET target.UserStatus = source.UserStatus
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Entity,UserName,UserRole,UserStatus,UpdatedDate)
    VALUES (Entity,UserName,UserRole,UserStatus,UpdatedDate);
          " )

# Remove temporary table
dbExecute(conn,"DROP TABLE #NEWDATA" )

# Check results
result <- dbGetQuery(conn,"SELECT * from TBL")
result

  ID Entity UserName UserRole UserStatus UpdatedDate
1  1      A     Ford  Analyst     Active    1/1/2020
2  2      B    Acura  Analyst     Active    1/5/2020
3  3      A    Tesla Engineer   Inactive    1/6/2020
4  4      A      Kia  Analyst     Active    1/1/2020
5 NA      A   Accord  Analyst     Active   1/10/2020
6 NA      C      BMW Engineer     Active   1/10/2020
```

Not sure how `ID` is managed on the server : autonumber?

Comment: Thnks! yes. ID is autonumber. Will this process suffer if for some reason multiple people login to make changes at the same time; table creation and deletion...

Comment: According to [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806962/13513328) shared by @CharlieFace, `HOLDLOCK` should protect against concurrency problems.

Comment: I implemented the above method and it worked! I also did try with the 'for loop' that checks if a certain row already exists and it worked as well. Of course, the MERGE option is way faster, in my opinion and that will be my approach. thnx for the suggestions @waldi